What happens inside javascript-based Pages if power goes off (PC shutting down suddently) (ex: Vue)
Maybe this is a silly question,
Regarding Vue 3 lifecycle hooks.
Any idea if a lifecycle hook of unmounted or something like the old Vue 2 destroyed is called, if there is a sudden power off (cut of electricity or batery died), and the computer shuts down before closing the page or the navigator. I'm not sure if the application interprets this a unmounted event + have time to execute within the unmounted hook.
This question presented itself while studying the possibility of saving the application data only inside this (unmounted) hook.
This question is also valid for other frameworks, such as Angular, but I'm more interested in Vue.
Thank you in advance,
Carlota

Everything in Javascript page is lost, no matter what framework you use.   It's your responsibility to save the data, eg. localeStorage, or remote storage etc.  And this happens when you tell it.   Using unmouted hooks might also be a bad idea regardless, as often this is run sync, and if you want to save async state your in trouble.

Because there's no warning during a sudden power outage the application wouldn't have a chance to do anything.

If the power cuts out everything stops. And happens immediately. Well, maybe you have a second. At most. But I don't see how you expect the code to 1. recognise no power (you recognise it by, you know, the computer stopping) and 2. save anything within the at most a second you have. It's about equivalent to saying "If a bomb explodes in my face, would I have time to put on my sunglasses"

Nothing will have the time to do anything. Not even the OS. Yes it is that far deep.
There is nothing you can do when the machine loses power because the CPU (and GPU if any) shuts down. The applications running on the OS and even the OS cannot do anything if the CPU is switched off.
Losing power is not something a software engineer can handle because it is beyond the scope of any software to handle. If losing power is a possibility that will destroy any important work in progress, you have to consider other design possibilities and in many cases, there is none.
I know how many times I had to create a fresh Ubuntu install on my machine because I lost power and my battery died in the process of an OS upgrade.

Thank you very much !! I'm wondering live saving into a database, but I would have to search for a solution that was performant and not too much resources intensive.
